# Reuse Zeppelin Interpreter settings

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Is any chance I can bring Zeppelin interpreter settings from another Zeppelin cluster ?

I made some changes in `Zeppelin` `spark` interpreter. I'd like to save these changes and use on different cluster .

Is it interpreter.json file ?

I didn't find documentation how to save and re-use interpreter configuration. I've read about ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DIR and configure it but cannot find in there latest json with updated configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is interpreter.json file. The file contains the interpreter configuration and notebook's interpreter binding info.

But I may not suggest you reuse the interpreter.json file from origin cluster to new cluster. Except that the new cluster need the same interpreter configuration and notebook's interpreter binding information.